# Why is this C Program not running on Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c, controls, malloc, runtime

I am tried to run after building this without any warnings or errors in Visual Studio .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int e = 0;
int num = 0;
int a = 0;
int n = 0;
int c = 0;

static int factorial();

int factorial(int e){
  if (e == 0)
    return 1;
  else if (e == 1)
    return 1;
  else
  return e * factorial(e - 1);
}

int main() {
  int k = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int f = 0;
  int r = 0;

  printf_s(" Enter a number for length of string");  
  scanf_s("%d", &n);
  printf_s(" Enter a number for choice of string");
  scanf_s("%d", &k);
  f = factorial(n) / (factorial(n - 2) * 2);
  char **arr = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = (char*)malloc(f * sizeof(char));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < f; j++) {
      *(*(arr + i) + j) = '\0';
    }
  }

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    num = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
      while (num <= n){
        if ((num == j) || (num == i))
          arr[r][num] = 'b';
        else
          arr[r][num] = 'a';
      }
    }
    r++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for    j = 0; j < f; j++) {
      printf_s("%c ", arr[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The control goes out of control after taking the inputs .
Whitespace characters , new line , any characters , strings or gibberish doesn't make any
difference . I also have my doubts about my calling the factorial function
like an expression .

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your code to make it more readable.  "Control goes out of control after taking the inputs" - this is a frustratingly vague description.  What inputs did you provide, and what was the behavior?  Did the program crash?  Did you not get the expected output?  Did it not terminate?

Comment: One problem that I see immediately is that you are not properly terminating your strings - In your middle loop where you're writing `'a'` and `'b'` to `arr[r][num]`, you need to loop while `num` is strictly *less than* `n` (`while (num < n)`) and that the end of the loop write `arr[r][num] = 0;`.

Comment: I doubt that you can build this program without any errors. The line `for    j = 0; j < f; j++) {` should not compile. Did you forget to increment `num` in the body of `while (num <= n){`? Is the `num = 0;` correct in the outer `for` loop or should it be in the inner loop before the `while` loop?

Comment: Maybe it might help knowing that `factorial(n) / (factorial(n - 2) * 2)` is the same as `n*(n-1)/2`. Simplier, isn't it?

Comment: @MauryaMoharar: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

I know this should be a comment but since I am lacking on reputation points, I can't comment. But from what I understand this code snippet:

```
'for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for    j = 0; j < f; j++) {
      printf_s("%c ", arr[j][i]);
    }
  }
}'
```

has an error; there should be a opening bracket in the second for loop. How did you manage to run it in spite of a compilation error to get a run time error I don't know. I think you pasted an older version of your code. Apart from that I admit I don't even know about printf_s() function. and from what I ran on my system it is throwing a undefined reference to both printf_s() and scanf_s(). If its a built in function make sure you have included its header file. Apart from that in this code snippet:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    num = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
      while (num <= n){
        if ((num == j) || (num == i))
          arr[r][num] = 'b';
        else
          arr[r][num] = 'a';
      }
    }
    r++;
  }
```

in the while loop `num` and `n` do not change so it is an infinite loop. I think that is the main reason for your error.

Comment: Actually, while copying this code the brackett got deleted . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

**factorial()** is ok, but there is no point in writing **else** after **return**

```
int factorial(int e)
{
    if (e == 0) return 1;
    if (e == 1) return 1;
    return e * factorial(e - 1);
};
```

sure you can also write a single **if()** using **||**

Your prototype for factorial is missing the parameter as in
`int factorial(int);`

A left **'('** is missing at line 56, the **for j = 0** as pointed by others

In this code

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char*)malloc(f * sizeof(char));
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < f; j++) {
        *(*(arr + i) + j) = '\0';
    }
}
```

You can initialize the strings in the first loop. No need to go again looping into them

Note that the **safe** version of `scanf()` expect a size parameter for each specifier of type **%c %s or %[ ]** (not the case here, you are using %d only).

Could you write a bit more on the logic of the program?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in using the factorial function to compute `f`:

```
f = factorial(n) / (factorial(n - 2) * 2);
```

`factorial` grows **very** quickly. You implementation exceeds the range of type `int` for `n = 13`. Technically you get undefined behavior, in practice the value computed for `f` is meaningless, it could even be negative and the division will crash if `factorial(n - 2)` computes to `0`, which will happen for any value of `n` larger than `35`.

Here is a much simpler expression which is valid up to `n = 46340`:

```
f = n * (n - 1) / 2;
```

There are other problems in the code:

- you do not test for `scanf_s()` failure to read numbers
- you do not test for allocation failure
- using `arr[i] = calloc(f, sizeof(char));` would prevent the need for the initialization loops as the indirect 2D matrix would already be initialized to all bits 0.
- `num` is not modified in the loop `while (num <= n)`, which makes it an infinite loop, another good explanation for your observations
- `k` is not used anywhere
- it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Some comments might help casual readers of your code.